# Change shell within a script between shell and tcsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

I have a situation where my default shell is set to sh or bash in the script. I have to change my shell in order to execute certain commands in tcsh. When I am doing this, I am not able to set the variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
Variables=/path/set

 tcsh
vendor_command.sh

ret=$?

if (ret!= 0)
exit "$ret"
else
echo "success"
fi
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, you cannot make tcsh variables be inherited by a calling bash script. Also, calling `tcsh` in your script (in the manner in which you're doing so) doesn't do what you think it does: Lines below that one are only executed *after* `tcsh` exits; they *are not* executed in tcsh itself.

Comment: Anyhow -- why are you doing that at all? It'd be trivial to rewrite your `if` statement to be compatible with POSIX sh.

Comment: Please clarify your situation.  I'm guessing that `vendor_command.sh` is a C shell script that sets some variables, and maybe runs some commands.  Is it run directly as shown, or do you need to 'source' it (`source` command in C shell — and Bash; `.` command in real shells — and Bash).  _Oops: bias creeping in!_  Is the code at the end of your fragment supposed to be C shell or Bash code?  AFAICS, it is neither, which is confusing.  There are various techniques to deal with the problem, but they're rococo enough that I need to understand what you're trying to do before outlining anything.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to be in tcsh yourself to run a tcsh script. If your vendor script requires tcsh but has no shebang, just run `tcsh vendor_script.sh` -- and, perhaps, file a bug with your vendor for putting a misleading extension on their filenames (and not using a proper shebang to allow the operating system to select an appropriate interpreter itself).

Comment: Joanthan Leffler.. Yes I have to source for my vendor variables to be initialized..

Answer (score 3):

Answering the literal question: **No, you cannot seamlessly switch between scripting languages, passing shell-local variables bidirectionally between them, without implementing that data-passing protocol yourself.**

You *can* embed a tcsh script in your POSIX sh script, as so:

```
#!/bin/sh
# this is run with POSIX sh
export var1="tcsh can see this"
var2="tcsh cannot see this"

tcsh <<'EOF'
# this is run with tcsh
# exported variables (not shell-local variables!) from above are present
var3="calling shell cannot see this, even if exported"
EOF

# this is run in the original POSIX sh shell after tcsh has exited
# only variables set in the POSIX shell, not variables set by tcsh, are available
```

...however, when the tcsh interpreter exits, all its variables disappear with it. To pass state around otherwise, you'd need to either emit content on stdout and read or evaluate it; write contents to a file; or otherwise explicitly implement some interface to pass data between the two scripts.

---

All that said, your example is trivially rewritten with no need for tcsh at all:

```
#!/bin/sh -a
# the -a above makes your variables automatically exported
# ...so that they can be seen by the vendor's script.

Variables=/path/set

# If vendor_command exits with a nonzero exit status, this
# ...makes the script exit with that same status.
vendor_command.sh || exit

echo "success"
```

Comment: Under one reasonable set of assumptions, it really can be this simple.